# ggplot2 fails to load, with 'rlang' package error

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

This is the error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required

In addition to a Warning message:

> package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.1

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Restart R so there are no packages loaded. Install the latest version of rlang with `install.packages("rlang")` and then `install.packages("ggplot2")`. It's unclear how you may have gotten the dependencies out of sync; normally that's not very easy to do unless you are installing packages in an unusual way.

Comment: thank you very much, worked for me after updating the R and Rstudio to the latest version.

Comment: This is a rather bizarre type of error... in my case I re-installed R and RStudio and used the code `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")` to solve this issue. Very inconvenient...

Answer (score 5):

Just providing a more complete answer for people to follow.

Remove packages with

```
remove.packages("rlang")
```

That may not work as you may need to delete the package from your R library. To find where you R library is run

```
.libPaths()
```

Once you've deleted the rlang folder from there you can restart R and run

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.9.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source") # for specific rlang version, in this case 0.4.9. For latest version can run install.packages("rlang")
packageVersion("rlang") #to check you now have rlang version you want
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured just a slight modification to the first answer worked best for me:
restart R, then:

```
remove.packages("rlang")
remove.packages("dplyr")

install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("dplyr")

library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to **restart R** and then update all the packages.

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

The problem with just removing & installing `rlang`, and then your desired package (here `ggplot2`), you might find there are other packages you have remove and install. Best to update all and save time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by updating the R and Rstudio, removing "rlang" package and reinstalling the package, removing "ggplot2" package and reinstalling the package back.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your R package, because there is a new update in the ggplot2 package which supports the higher R ver, it should be 3.6.3 and greater !