# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've encountered the following error while trying to do some basic introductory exercises to familiarize myself with this package.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

I then get this error code at this point

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:  .onLoad failed
> in loadNamespace() for 'rlang', details:   call:
> readRDS(nsInfoFilePath)   error: unknown input format

I've manually verified the package's installation and directory but I still get this error.

Any insights? I feel like I'm missing something extremely basic here.

Comment: The error mentions the `rlang` package, perhaps try reinstalling that with `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: Please choose a title which would be useful for others with the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't have an accepted answer, but otherwise, this question seems to be a [duplicate of that one asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270923/ggplot2-fails-to-load-with-rlang-package-error).  As @GregorThomas noted, the error refers to `rlang`.  Try installing / updating `rlang` separately, then update and load `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas I tried installing "rlang" and attempted library (rlang) and got a new error:  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rlang', details:
  call: readRDS(nsInfoFilePath)
  error: unknown input format

Comment: What OS and R version are you using? It sounds like something very unusual happened to your R library. See this question for the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick Win10, the latest R and Rstudio for x64 downloaded from the website

Comment: I know this sounds like silly advice, but have you tried quitting and restarting?

Comment: Also, ensure you library directory is not on a shared drive or (if using Win10) OneDrive.  R doesn't behave very well sometimes when libraries are on shared drives.  Restarting with a clean R session (no extra packages loaded) is also suggested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073165/r-many-package-imports-have-issues-related-to-pillar is unanswered, but suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762660/r-cannot-find-llapack-cannot-find-lblas

Comment: @camille I did indeed. A clean uninstall and reinstall seemed to solve my woes. I also manually created a library directory in my R folder which seemed to help?