# Error package or namespace (tidyverse and lubridate library)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm having the following problem when running a script from my work, it always returns an error like this one from print to library Lubridate or tidyverse

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required
> library(openxlsx)
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66782751/namespace-rlang-0-4-5-is-being-loaded-but-0-4-10-is-required) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270923/ggplot2-fails-to-load-with-rlang-package-error or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799143/namespace-rlang-0-4-9-is-being-loaded-but-0-4-10-is-required

Comment: `rlang` version 1.0.2 requires R [version 3.4.0 or later](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/commit/d9cc605124ad7ea34a289c1cde6cc3832bf9415c). Might need to either update R and installed packages or install older versions of tidyverse packages which don't require rlang 1.0.2

Comment: my version in the Rstudio is 3.6.3

Comment: And another, even the lubridate library is giving error

Comment: funny that when I run only the library(tidyverse) line of code it doesn't give an error, just normal conflict with dplyr, but when I run the whole script it returns this rlang 1.0.2 request error

Comment: Since you are using a ```.libpaths``` I am asuming it is a general map where multiple users can use the packages from. (Speaking from experience) maybe someone accidentally altered a file or map. Ask the one responsible for the library map to refresh/update the map